# Graph of a Set of Complex Numbers satisfying a Particular Condition

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What would be the graph of the following set:

$$\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z-1|\lt |z|\}$$

I tried out writing $z$ as $x+iy$, squaring both sides and ultimately came up with the condition on $x$ as $x \lt \frac{1}{2}$.

Help me judge where I am wrong and correct me. Thanks

Comment: These are the complex numbers that are closer to $1$ than to $0$. The line of equal distance is ... In other words, there is nothing wrong with your result.

Comment: Is it $x=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Yes, that is the separating line. The solution set, as you observed, is the half-plane left of it.

Comment: Would the graph just then be the left half plane to the dashed line $x=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @ParasKhosla $z$ has to be closer to $1$ than it is to $0$, so the solution set is the *right* half plane bounded by the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$. In other words it is the half plane $x > \frac{1}{2}$. Your original answer was almost correct but you must have got a sign switched somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, from my first observation to the next ones I must have mentally switched the same sign. Closer to $1$ of course includes $z=1$ which indicates again what half-plane to chose.

Answer (score 1):

$(x-1)^2+y^2 < x^2+y^2\\\Rightarrow -2x+1<0\\\Rightarrow 2x>1 \\\Rightarrow x > \frac{1}{2}$